# How to change the display format on a P13nItem TimePicker/DatePicker?

Tags: javascript, formatting, sapui5

I'm trying to change the display format on the DatePicker/TimePicker used by the sap.m.P13nItem when the selected column type is date/time.

I have tried changing the aggregation P13nItem from the P13nFilterPanel in order to include the property formatSettings, but it didn't work.

Here is a sample of my XML view code.

```
<P13nFilterPanel id="filterPanel" visible="true" type="filter" containerQuery="true" items="{
                    path: 'SchedulingFilter>/ColumnCollectionFilter'
                }" filterItems="{
                    path: 'SchedulingFilter>/FilterItems'
                }">
                <P13nItem columnKey="{SchedulingFilter>columnKey}" text="{SchedulingFilter>label}" type="{SchedulingFilter>type}" maxLength="{SchedulingFilter>maxLength}" formatSettings="{SchedulingFilter>formatSettings>" />
                <filterItems>
                    <P13nFilterItem columnKey="{SchedulingFilter>keyField}" operation="{SchedulingFilter>operation}" value1="{SchedulingFilter>value1}" value2="{SchedulingFilter>value2}" exclude="{SchedulingFilter>exclude}" />
                </filterItems>
            </P13nFilterPanel>
```

Here is an extract of how I'm filling the bound data.

```
$.each(columnsKeys, function (i, item) {
            const columnData = {};
            const columnDescriptionItem = columnDescription[item];
            columnData.columnKey = item;
            columnData.text = columnDescriptionItem.label;
            columnData.type = columnDescriptionItem.type;
            columnData.formatSettings = {
                pattern: 'yyyy/MM/dd',
                UTC: false
            };
            columnData.maxLength = columnDescriptionItem.maxLength;
            columnData.visible = columnDescriptionItem.visible;
            columnData.index = columnDescriptionItem.index;
            columnData.isEditable = columnDescriptionItem.isEditable;
            columnData.isFilter = columnDescriptionItem.isFilter;
            columnData.isSorter = columnDescriptionItem.isSorter;
            columnsData.push(columnData);
        });
```

The default behavior of the control displays the time/date fields as:
https://ibb.co/JcJJZhJ.

Edit: I discovered that the default behavior is based on the user's locale. I'm not considering the user's locale to change the display format on the others parts of my application.

I want to achieve, for example, the display formats "yyyy/MM/dd" and "hh:mm:ss" on these fields.

Comment: What's in your `formatSettings` on the p13nitem? Side note, filtering is probably easier if you combined date and time into a DateTimePicker (if you have control over this, I'm not sure

Comment: My formatSetings has the following attributes: { pattern: 'yyyy/MM/dd',
                UTC: false }. It's not interesting for me to merge both date and time filters into one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to extend the P13nConditionPanel (this one is responsible for the time/date components instantiation) and the P13nFilterPanel (it creates the P13nConditionPanel) on version 1.44.6 of SAPUI5 in order to solve this problem. I only had to add the necessary parameters to the DatePicker and TimePicker constructors (as shown below).

```
case "date":
                oConditionGrid.oFormatter = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateInstance();
                params.displayFormat = DateFormatter.displayFormat();
                oControl = new sap.m.DatePicker(params);
                break;
case "time":
                oConditionGrid.oFormatter = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getTimeInstance();
                params.displayFormat = TimeFormatter.getDisplayFormat();
                oControl = new sap.m.TimePicker(params);
```

I posted my customized extended components code on pastebin:

[Customized P13nConditionPanel](https://pastebin.com/vSDW97jy)

[Customized P13nFilterPanel](https://pastebin.com/e2ctp78A)

I will later open an enhancement request on openui5 Github.